# Push Notification - Dedicated server required?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, hosting, mpns

I'm thinking of developing an app that uses Microsoft Push Notification. However, I'm not quite sure what I need on my server. I've currently got a shared hosting account. Can I use this as my server to use Push Notification, or does the server have to be dedicated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes you can use shared or dedicated hosting to send out push notifications. Shared just means there are other web servers running on the same physical hardware which does not effect the api's available to your service.

You can get some more background on this if you want to check out Peter Torr's Mix 2010 talk on the video at around 28 minutes in.